# How do you get and display json objects created by rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I've seen examples of getting arrays made into json but not pure variables. I'm new to json and need a ajax /javascript function that can print out the contents of something like this:

```
{"name":["1"],"email":["1"],"phone":["1"],"subject":["1"],"message":["1"]}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "print out"? Where is the data coming from and in what format, and exactly what do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

I created a jsfiddle.net that shows you how you could do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/6kLfk/

The javascript is this:

```
var data = {
"name": ["1"],
"email": ["1"],
"phone": ["1"],
"subject": ["1"],
"message": ["1"]
}

$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    $('#test').append(key + ": " + value + "<br />");
});
```

which outputs:

```
name: 1
email: 1
phone: 1
subject: 1
message: 1
```

Comment: That seems to be a good start but that code seems static. I'd like to get the parameter "name" or "email" etc. that rails builds.